# Find OleDb drivers available on Windows

Tags: .net, excel, windows, oledb

I have a project that opens an Excel workbook using an OleDB connection.  Different people have different versions of Office installed though.

If the connection string is created like this:

```cs
var connectionString = $"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Extended Properties=Excel 12.0 XML;Data Source={workBookFilePath}";
```

Some users will get an exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException : 
    The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.
```

How can I intelligently get a provider that is available on the machine and only throw and exception if there aren't any?

Comment: Does specifying `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB` without the version suffix work?

Comment: @JeroenMostert It didn't.  I'll try again though, there has been a reboot since I tried it.

Comment: @JeroenMostert.  Same exception (just different provider stated).  Is there any syntax for "Any version above x.y.z"?

Comment: Later versions should also install (or at least support) the "lower" providers, so you should be able to get away with always specifying the lowest version that will support the workbook versions you're using. But if not, I guess you'll have to get explicit with [`OleDbEnumerator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.oledb.oledbenumerator.getelements).

Comment: @JeroenMostert I thinkg that `OldDbEnumerator` class is just what I'm looking for.  Thanks.

Comment: @JeroenMostert That enumerator says I have both `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` & `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.15.0`.  I still get the exception though (for both).

Comment: Bitness? These drivers are 32-bit only. Are you enumerating and connecting from the same code base?

Comment: @JeroenMostert Maybe, the OS is x64 but Office is x86.  I definitely can't install the x64 drivers as the installer says there are x86 Office products on the machine.

Comment: @JeroenMostert `Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0` throws the same exception, so I wonder if the problem is somewhere else then.

Comment: Jet is also 32-bit only. Is the code that's making the connection actually running as 32-bit? That is, is your project set to compile code to x86?

Comment: The platform target is "Any CPU".

Comment: @JeroenMostert That's it.  Change to x86 and everything's OK.  Thanks for the help.  I don't know how long it would have taken me to reach that conclusion!